# how to convert windows.forms.keys code to integer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i have a project in which i have assigned some functions to single characters(e.g. Keyboard Key "H" will do high pass filtering).

Now To get "H" as an output i have created a down event which hopefully pick up the keys are down and calls the function with an integer value. However I get an error when i try to compare the input value with an integer value in the function. The following is my code...

```
public static event DownEventHandler Down;
public static delegate void DownEventHandler(string Key);
Down(FunctionChar((Keys)lParam.Code));    // lParam.code is an integer value.

private string FunctionChar(Keys e)
{

      if(e >=65 && e<=90){

          if (Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.CapsLock) || ((Control.ModifierKeys !=0) && (Keys.Shift) != 0))
            {
                return e.ToString;
            }
            else
            {
                return e.ToString.ToLower;
            }
```

}

I assume that this function will give me the output a string either "G" or "g". as mentioned before i want to use it in further functionality.

However it gives me error as following.

```
Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Keys' and 'int'
```

I know one of the solution is to use SWITCH statement but i want to use if statement and not switch.

Can some one tell me - what is the problem? What values does "e" posses and how can i convert it to (Int) so i can use it in the IF statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't compare `System.Windows.Forms.Key` with and `Integer` so you have to convert the `key` has been converted to an integer before you compare them. here is an example for you:

```
 Keys e = Keys.A;
 int keyVal= (int)e;// return 65
```

So you can do like this:

```
 if((int)e >=65 && (int)e<=90)
{
// your code goes here 
}
```

Another way for doing this is:

```
  if(e >= Keys.A&& e<= Keys.Z)
    {
    // your code goes here 
    }
```

**Update :**
You can return the corresponding character using : `return ((char)e).ToString();`

Hence the whole function signature will be like the following:

```
private string FunctionChar(Keys e)
        {

            if ((int)e >= 65 && (int)e <= 90)
            {

                if (Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.CapsLock) || ((Control.ModifierKeys != 0) && (Keys.Shift) != 0))
                {
                    return ((char)e).ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    return ((char)e).ToString().ToLower();
                }
            }
            return "";
        }
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. However after the ' if((int)e >=65 && (int)e<=90) ' this comparison it still gives me **error in the parentheses** when i try to return as ** ' return e.ToString ' ** Do you know how can i solve that? i tried ' return (int)e.ToString ' but it didn't work. I am still confused why it does that.

Comment: @ the-newbieprogramer: See the updates in the answer

Answer (score 1):

When working with an enum, such as `Keys`, it's better design to express any conditions in terms of the enum's values, rather than casting back to `int`s.

So I'd recommend replacing:
`if(e >=65 && e<=90)`
with
`if (e >= Keys.A && e <= Keys.Z)`.

This should compile fine - and your intention is clearer to anyone reading your code!

Comment: i tried your solution, the error code in the **if** statement went away but i still get error in the parentheses after  **if** statement. I still can't use **return e.ToString**. Do you know may be why?

Comment: You need brackets with ToString, it's a method call: `return e.ToString();`

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather not use *magic numbers* but actual *chacraters*, and I'd write an *extension method(s)* for this:

```
  public static class KeysExtensions
  {
    public static Boolean IsLetter(this Keys value)
    {
      return value >= Keys.A && value <= Keys.Z;
    }
  }
```

So when handling events you can put *readable* code:

```
  private void Something_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.KeyCode.IsLetter())
    {
     // Do your operations here...
    }
  }
```

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms.Key` Does not contains definition for `IsLetter()`

Comment: @un-lucky: that's why I think it would be useful to implement it (`IsLetter()`) as an *extension method*